# How to calculate time complexity of two loops (number of actions)?

Tags: algorithm, loops, math, language-agnostic, complexity-theory

I am not sure how to calculate the time complexity of the two loops.

i runs from 1 to n: 1,2,3,4,5,...,n

j runs from 1 to i; 1,2,4,8,...,i

when  i = 1
j: 1
loop runs: 1 time

when  i = 2
j: 1,2
loop runs: 2 times

when  i = 3
j: 1,2
loop runs: 2 times

when  i = 4
j: 1,2,4
loop runs: 3 times

when  i = 5
j: 1,2,4
loop runs: 3 times
.... 
when  i = n
j: 1,2,4,8,...,n 
loop runs: logn+1 times

so the loop runs (number of time): 1+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+...+(logn+1)

So I don't understand the constancy.
How can I create the sigma of this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to evaluate Big-O for your cycle and there's no other dependencies, you can use the following estimation:

```
O(Full Cycle) = O(Outer Cycle)*O(Inner Cycle) = O(N)*O(log2(N)) = O(N log(N))
```

(second estimation goes simply by definition, since we are looking big O and we know that cycle will iterate till `j*2 < i` and also `i < n`)

Comment: I thought I need to show theta no ?  
by the way, I just notice that the number of runs is:   
1+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+...+logn

which is: 1+4+12+64+...+logn
which is: 1*1+2*2+3*4+4*8+...+logn
And then I will receive:
Sigma(i=1..logn+1)[i*2^(i-1)] 
  
upper bound: (logn+1)n ==> O(n log(n))  
lower bound: Omega(n log(n))

Comment: by the way,

is it correct if I was creating two sigmas:
[∑(i=1 to n)]*[∑(j=1 to logi+1) of 1] = ∑(i=1 to n) of (logi + 1)
upper bound: nlogn + n = O(nlogn)
lower bound: [∑(i=1 to n/2) of log(i)] + [∑(i=(n/2)+1 to n/2) of log(i)] <= (n/2)log((n/2)+1) + n/2 = Omega(nlogn)

Comment: You can create sigmas with double indexes. Second sigma will be |log2(n)| where |x| is minimal closest integer